# Boost property_tree time complexity

Tags: c++, xml, boost, boost-propertytree

What is the time complexity of using boost property tree's get_child_optional method? How fast or slow is it as compared to std::unordered_map lookup if we store node name and property_tree as KV pair?

No doc found for the same

Answer (score 0):

It calls `walk_path()` to do most of the work, which is [here](https://github.com/boostorg/property_tree/blob/88a3b0ba8a6cd4ddf35f10d841bde9878241d64a/include/boost/property_tree/detail/ptree_implementation.hpp#L885-L900)

```cpp
        // Recurse down the tree to find the path.
        key_type fragment = p.reduce();
        const_assoc_iterator el = find(fragment);
        if(el == not_found()) {
            // No such child.
            return 0;
        }
        // Not done yet, recurse.
        return el->second.walk_path(p);
```

But what about that `find()`?  It is on a [Boost Multi-Index container](https://github.com/boostorg/property_tree/blob/88a3b0ba8a6cd4ddf35f10d841bde9878241d64a/include/boost/property_tree/detail/ptree_implementation.hpp#L40-L51), and that `ordered_non_unique` type is documented [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/multi_index/doc/reference/ord_indices.html#complexity_signature)

So in total it is **O(n log m)**: linear time in the number of path components **n** you pass to `get_child_optional()`, and logarithmic time in the number of children **m** at each step in the recursion through the path components.

> How fast or slow is it as compared to std::unordered_map lookup?

You'll have to test that with your actual data to find out.

Comment: Multi-index is very decent on performance. Boost Property Tree is not, though. Don't use for anything that should scale (or uses JSON or XML for that matter, because the library was not designed for those tasks). Lookups on existing `ptree` should be reasonably fine thanks to MultiIndex. But "unordered_map" implies volumes that I would never put through PropertyTree. Besides the obviousness that people really rarely have property tree needs. I'd 100% use Boost JSON in stead. Even for classical PropertyTree applications (like config objects)

Comment: @sehe: I agree that Boost Property Tree is dead slow in practice.  I have had the unfortunate experience of using it to parse moderately large XML documents (like 50 MB) and it is horrible for that.